# LaTeX vs pdflatex on \neq

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, dvi

Using LaTeX for `.dvi` output produces unexpected result for `\neq`, instead of the `\neq`, it's displaying `=` though `pdflatex` provides the correct symbol.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using [flashcard.cls](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/misc/flashcard.cls)

```
\begin{flashcard}{Weak Axiom}
  \begin{itemize}
     \item In words: A consumer faces $(p,w)$ chooses $x(p,w)$ in lieu of $x(p^{\prime},w^{\prime})$. If $x(p^{\prime},w^{\prime})$ is ever chosen, $x(p,w)$ must not be affordable.
     \item $p{x}({p}^\prime,{w}^\prime)\leq w \mbox{ and } x(p^{\prime},w^{\prime}) \neq x(p,w) \Rightarrow {p}^\prime x(p,w) > {w}^\prime $
  \end{itemize}
\end{flashcard}
```

[image]

Comment: As for me I can't see any problem there. I compiled it but I didn't get any difference.

Comment: Testing with other PDF viewers could also help. Screen rendering issues are not uncommon (I'm looking at you, Adobe Reader/Acrobat!), but printed output should be the same.

Comment: @jasper what does 'too faintly' mean? using ghostscript.

Comment: You can always use `\not=` instead of `\neq`.

Comment: Same here. DVI displays an eqals, PDF has a not-equals. Does not depend on resolution.
No special packages loaded. This is Ubuntu 11.10, distro installation.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) Creating the pdf with dvipdf, the pdf looks fine.
Runnign pdflatex, also fine.
May be an evince problem. See
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=571701

Comment: I am having the same problem using Evince (a.k.a. "Document Viewer" in Ubuntu) to view the dvi. Zooming into the character unambiguously shows what should be \neq is rendering as "=" in Evince. But using Okular it renders correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a symbol from a package instead of the default `\neq`, such as

- `\neq` of `mathabx`
- `\nequal`, `\ne` or `\neq` of `MnSymbol`, all meaning the same
- The default `\neq` is defined as `\not=`, in `fontmath.ltx`, you could also try using `\not=` in case `\neq` has been overwritten by a package. `\not` is originally defined by `\DeclareMathSymbol{\not}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"36}`.
- The `cancel` package offers an alternative by `\cancel{=}`.
- Finally, check if it's just a viewer issue by zooming, printing and trying a different viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The `\neq` is not displayed properly within a .dvi, but you can use `dvips` to convert the .dvi to a .ps, and it should be displayed properly. If you need a .pdf, you can then use `ps2pdf` (I actually find this to have better formatting success in general than using `pdflatex` directly.)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a comment (not an answer)?